# XNA- Looking for an algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna-4.0

I've been bashing my head for the past couple of weeks trying to find an algorithm that would help me accomplish, on first look very easy task regarding `Vector3's`. So, I got this one object made out of 5 cubes(2 **sides**, 1 **top**, 1 **bottom**, 1 **back**, (and there will probably be the **front** cubes)). Now I want to make it so when I want to `Scale(2,1,1);` the whole object lets say on **X** axis only on the **top** and the **bottom** cube would get scaled. And the **side** cubes should only change their position(so their **X** dimension stays exactly the same). The problem is with the **back** side. Because it does not fully cover the back side, thus if I were to `Scale(2,1,1);` it, it would then leave this gap on each side, which I do not want. The same principle should go for all axis. For **Y** I would `Scale();` the side cubes,  and only move the top and bottom cubes, and apply a this diffrent scale on the back side. For the **Z** axis I would `Scale();` both the **sides**, **top** and **bottom** cubes, and only move the **back** cube.

Here are the images of an example object:

**Back of the object:**

http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/3125/backyd.png

**Side of the object:**

http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/6796/fromtheside.png

**Front of the object:**

http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/281/frontxh.png

Hope you can help,

---

**EDIT:**
I am sorry, I wasnt clear enought, when I `Scale();` an object,lets say on **X** axis, like I said before want to `Scale();` only the **top** and **bottom** cube. Now, about the **side** cubes, I want to move them so they are positioned just like before, in this case on both ends of the **top** and **bottom** cubes.

Comment: Have you tried [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) ? You're more likely to find what you are looking for there.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned , for **X** I tried scaling **top** and **bottom** by some factor. Then moving **sides** by some factor/2, but there was a problem if one of the sides is positioned negatively e.g, -0.4, because it moves both by same factor.So,I never really got close to any decent results.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I will try it if I wont get a response here.

Comment: @user1806687 Consider the box as an inside surface and outside surface (which here happen to coincide on one face). Scale the outside, recompute the inside given box thickness. Done. ...I should post this as an answer, but I'm not an XNA guy myself.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to have a parent matrix for the whole array and just scale that? Or are you worried about preserving the thickness of the walls?